# How to set Scroll Position to Top of the browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, scrollbar, menuitem

In `c#` i am using Menus.When i was clicking on next menu the browser scroll bar is taking previous menu scroll bar position.

```
<asp:Menu ID="menuTab" Width="168px" runat="server" RenderingMode="Table" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"
StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="tab" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="selectedTab"
CssClass="tabs">
<Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text='Name'
        Value="0" Selected="true" />
    <asp:MenuItem Text='Details'
        Value="1" Selectable="false" />
</Items>
```

If i click on Second menu details page scroll bar is placed in bottom of the page.
I want to set the scroll bar position in top.

I was tried this below jquery code. Its not working

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    alert(tempScrollTop)

    $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
    //$(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

[image]

you can see this image.Scrollbar is placed in bottom of the page.
If i click next button scroll bar position is same.

[image]

Comment: when you click on `update` page will refreshing?

Comment: yes,page it wil get refresh when i click on update and next button.

Comment: `alert(tempScrollTop)` is working? return data?

Comment: its working the tempScrollTop value is coming 0

Comment: Okay, try this `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});`

Comment: i tried this its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 0);
});
```